# Vue.js - I'm getting nowhere very very slowly

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, import, tailwind-css

Everything appears to be unable to resolve the file paths for Home and App. I have even fed all of my files to AI and had it check. I've got nothing.

from main.js in the src folder:

> import Home from '@views/Home.vue'; // Using alias
> import App from '@src/App.vue'; // Using alias

from index.js in the router folder:

> import Home from '@views/Home.vue';
> import App from '@src/App.vue';

App.vue:

> ```
> <template>
> <div id="app">
> </div>
> </template>
>
> <script>
> export default {
> name: 'App',
> };
> </script>
>
> <style>
> </style>
> ```

Home.vue:

> ```
> <template>
> <div class="flex justify-center items-center h-screen ">
> <div class="bg-white p-10 rounded-lg shadow-lg">
> <h2 class="text-2xl mb-4">Sign in</h2>
> <form class="flex flex-col space-y-4">
> <input type="email" placeholder="Email" class="border p-2" />
> <button class="bg-blue-500 text-white p-2 rounded">Send Code</button>
> </form>
> </div>
> </div>
> </template>
> <script>
> export default {
> name: 'Home',
> };
> </script>
> <style scoped>
> </style>
> ```

I've tried everything I could think of, and everything AI could think of. It's an empty, brand new project. There's not much to check.

Comment: "Everything appears to be unable to resolve the file paths for Home and App"  - what is the meaning of this, how do you now the problem is in path resolution? "brand new project" - what is the project, how was it created? You're supposed to take care of `@views` and `@src` aliases in order for them to work at least, it's unknown why you used them. AI isn't a substitute for learning things you work with. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: "_Everything appears to be unable to resolve the file paths_", please include exact error messages in your question.  Aliases also must be configured in order to work.  Depending on your project this configuration is usually in `vite.config.js` or `vue.config.js`. This information would be important to include in your question.  The component code contains no errors, and since the issues seem to be in`main.js` and `index.js` it would be better to see more relevant code from those files such as how you're trying to use these imported components.

Answer (score 0):

I think a problem is in App.vue. So I recreated a little project with Vue 3 with your code and it works.
So this is `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Vite App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script type="module" src="/src/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is the default code I haven't changed it. `ìndex.html` is the mount point for your Vue application. The Vue instance attaches to this element and renders the components within it, starting with `App.vue`.

In this file there is link to `main.js`:

```
import './assets/main.css'

import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'

const app = createApp(App)

app.use(router)

app.mount('#app')
```

In a Vue.js application, `main.js` serves as the entry point for the application. It is the first file that gets executed when you run your Vue app.

Creating this application I decided to use a router so App.vue is like this:

```
<script setup>
import { RouterLink, RouterView } from 'vue-router'
</script>

<template>
  <header>
    <div class="wrapper">

      <nav>
        <RouterLink to="/">Home</RouterLink>
        <RouterLink to="/about">About</RouterLink>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>

  <RouterView />
</template>
```

In router folder there is `index.js` with routes:

```
mport { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'
import HomeView from '../views/HomeView.vue'

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(import.meta.env.BASE_URL),
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'home',
      component: HomeView
    },
    {
      path: '/about',
      name: 'about',
      // route level code-splitting
      // this generates a separate chunk (About.[hash].js) for this route
      // which is lazy-loaded when the route is visited.
      component: () => import('../views/AboutView.vue')
    }
  ]
})

export default router
```

`App.vue` serves as the root component from which all other components in the application are mounted or initiated. Essentially, it's the main entry point of a Vue 3 application.

If you want to use your own `App.vue`, without router, like in your example you need to use a file home in your App.vue for example like this:

```
<script setup>
import HomeView from './views/HomeView.vue';
</script>

<template>
  <div id="app">
    <HomeView/>
  </div>
</template>
```